# Alternative to println()?

Tags: kotlin

If we don't have the `println()` function, is there any alternative or a way to write your print function?

Comment: Could you... clarify?

Comment: Do you mean `println()`, or something else? (Computers need exact spelling, but it helps humans read it too…) If you just want to see how that function is implemented in the standard library, you can see its source code. Or if you have other constraints, you'll have to give some details.

Comment: `println()` is just a simple utility which underneath uses printing specific to the target, for example it uses `System.out.println()` in JVM and `console.log()` in JavaScript.

Comment: println(), interviewer asked me this " what if you don't have the print(), println() function how'd u print in the console"

Comment: I don't think there's a single answer to this — it depends just how much of the standard library your interviewer is dispensing with (Just that one stand-alone function? Related I/O methods? String methods?), and what functionality you need (Just writing simple strings? Concatenation? Full `%`-based formatting?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click on println in IntelliJ, you can `Go to...` -> `Implementation(s)` and see how Kotlin does it "under the hood". It's a bit verbose but not that complicated. Ultimately it's using a `BufferedWriter` to write to the Standard Output stream.

You can replicate this yourself with something like:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter


fun main() {
    val writer = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(System.`out`))
    writer.write("No println here")
    writer.newline()
    writer.flush()
}
```